# Find maximum value in dictionary of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

How do I find the *maximum value of the lists* in a *dictionary of lists* without using a loop? My dictionary looks like:

```
data = {'key1': list1, 'key2': list2, ... 'keyn': listn}
```

if I use:

```
m = max(data.iterkeys(), key=lambda k: data[k])
```

the output is:

```
m = 'keyn'
```

which I don't want to have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate through the items in each list in a generator expression:

```
m = max(i for v in data.values() for i in v)
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew that there was I way like this but (I'm new to python) I didn't get it

Comment: @themacco You could catch up with a little reading [Generator Expressions vs. List Comprehension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 3):

```
myDict = {'key1': [1,2,3], 'key2': [4,5,6]}
maxValue = max((max(myDict[key]) for key in myDict))
```

output: `6`

if your new to python, here is a much readable way of how Moses Koledoye did it:

```
for v in myDict.values():
    for i in v:
        m = i if i > m else m
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the maximum value like this. With out using any loop.

```
max(max(data.values()))
```

But this answer is valid when the all values are iterable.

```
In [1]: myDict = {'key1': [1,2,3], 'key2': [4,5,6]}
In [2]: max(max(myDict.values()))
Out[1]: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

The two answers which use the `max(max(dict.values()))` approach do not provide the right answer for a more generic dictionary.  They only work if the max value is in the list which has the maximum *first value* of all the lists.

The code below does *not* give 65 as the answer, but 53, which is the maximum of the list that has the maximum first value of all lists:

```
myDict = {'key1': [51,52,53], 'key2': [4,5,65]}
print(max(max(myDict.values())))
```

Instead, use this:

```
print(max(max(myDict.values(), key=lambda x: max(x))))
```

This approach does the following:

1. Find the list value that has the maximum value --- `max(myDict.values(), key=lambda x: max(x))`
2. Find the maximum value of that list --- the outer call to `max()`

This has the downside of iterating through the maximum value-containing list twice, so keep that in mind if you are operating on large lists.